# Why does scrollbar appears when i remove display: inline-block property from link and is there any another way to avoid scrollbar from appearing?

Tags: css, html, css-transitions

Why does scrollbar appears when i remove display: inline-block property from link and is there any another way to avoid scrollbar from appearing
    Php file -

```
<main>
    <div class="container">
        <h2>Test Your PHP Knowledge</h2>
        <p>This is a multiple choice quiz to test your knowledge of PHP</p>
        <ul>
            <li><strong>Number of Questions : </strong>5</li>
            <li><strong>Type : </strong>Multiple Choice</li>
            <li><strong>Estimated Time : </strong>4 Minutes</li>
        </ul>
        <a href="question.php?n=1" class="start">Start Quiz</a>
    </div>
</main>



body{
    font-family: arial;
    font-size: 15px;
    line-height: 1.6em;
}

.container{
    width: 60%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    overflow: auto;
}

header{
    border-bottom: 3px #f4f4f4 solid;

}

footer{
    border-top: 3px #f4f4f4 solid;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 5px;
}

main{
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    height: auto;
    overflow-y: auto;
}
```

What does below property display:inline-block does to avoid scrollbar in main area

Css File -

```
a.start{
    display: inline-block;
    color: #666;
    background: #f4f4f4;
    border: 1px dotted #ccc;
    padding: 6px 13px;
}
```

Comment: Try to remove the `overflow-y: auto;` or (?) `overflow: auto;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can see what happens when you give a background color to the container.
What happens here is that the padding to the `<a>` does not help increase the height of the container.

```css
.container {
  background:tan;
  padding:1px .5em;
}
.container a {
  padding:1em;
  background:#eee;
  border:1px solid;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
 <p>Some text here</p>
 <a>Some inline text here</a>
</div>
```

The system doesn't use the `<a>`'s padding for the calculations of the container's height, so the container incorporates the line height of the a, but not the bottom padding.
So the `<a>` overflows out of the container. Its padding does not have any effect on its positioning. (You also see that the top padding of the `<a>` is inside the bottom margin of the `<p>`.)

Now if you change the `<a>`'s display mode to `inline-block`, the whole picture changes: the padding does count; the container does grow to encompass its padding, and its top padding is no longer intruding on the `<p>`'s bottom margin.

```css
.container {
  overflow:visible;
  background:tan;
  padding:1px .5em;
}
.container a {
  display:inline-block;
  padding:1em;
  background:#eee;
  border:1px solid;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
 <p>Some text here</p>
 <a>Some inline-block text here</a>
</div>
```

So there are a couple of solutions:

1. Accept that things are as they are; keep the `<a>` an inline-block
2. Remove the `overflow:auto`, so that the `<a>` bleeds out of the container. This may affect elements on the screen below the container though
3. Don't use padding on the `<a>`
4. Put some other, block or inline-block, element in the container after the `<a>`.